# How to enable OIDC Authentication in Airflow (Flask App Builder)

Tags: airflow, openid-connect, flask-login, flask-appbuilder

I am working on enabling OIDC authentication in Apache Airflow (Built using FAB).

I have an URL (Something like https://api.login.yahoo.com) and the .well-known endpoint is returning a proper response (Just like https://api.login.yahoo.com/.well-known/openid-configuration)

When I see the [FAB Security help](https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#authentication-openid), the example for OIDC is

```
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OID

OPENID_PROVIDERS = [

{ 'name': 'Yahoo', 'url': 'https://me.yahoo.com' },
{ 'name': 'AOL', 'url': 'http://openid.aol.com/<username>' },
{ 'name': 'Flickr', 'url': 'http://www.flickr.com/<username>' },
{ 'name': 'MyOpenID', 'url': 'https://www.myopenid.com' }

]
```

I am confused, where is the client configuration? I have created a client in the Authentication Gateway Portal but am not sure where to configure it.

Please provide some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create it yourself, either manually or if using flask-oidc, there's a registration generator:

https://flask-oidc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#registration